# Filevault (or something else) preventing Nvidia drivers from loading

Tags: filevault, gpu

I attempted to migrate to a new mac pro, in preparation I did the following :

1. Using Carbon Copy Cloner, clone my primary drive to a new drive. The source drive was using file vault 2 and I ensured a recovery disk was created on the new drive.
2. Moved a Nvidia GTX 680 from my old machine into my new.
3. Booted up.

Here everything was working fine. However, then I turned on filevault as I had on my previous system. Then when I booted I just got a black screen. I slotted in an old NVidia GT120 and seemed to be able to get the login screen displaying and after log in the GTX 680 would start working again (It would only ever work after login when filevault is turned on).

I have tried quite a few steps to try and get the card work at boot; zapped the PRAM, reset SMC, reinstalled the NVidia web drivers and CUDA however I was still unable to get the card to put out a signal until after login.

I then turned filevault off and the 680 started working again during boot. I have replicated this twice, turn filevault on - loose the 680, turn it back off - get the 680 outputting.

What could be causing this issue?

Additional info :

- MacPro 4,1 OS X 10.8.4
- I recently installed more RAM
- Using a samsung 840 evo as the new drive.
- When I say the GTX 680 worked at boot I mean it will display the login screen.

Comment: Just an idea: are there any firmware updates available for the new machine?

Comment: No it seems all firmware is up to date, except maybe the samsung ssd which requires windows for updates.